# how to connect to database when server is in Unix socket?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem with the connection to database (phpmyadmin), it just because my server is in UNIX socket. I don't know how to connect to it (I'm stand on window). The code below is work fine, if my server is in TCP/IP.

**My code**

```
<?php

define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxxxx');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'sample_db');
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
$database = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_set_charset("utf8", $connection);

?>
```

Can anyone tell me how to connect to database, if the server is in UNIX socket?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit confused by your question.

> I'm stand on window

Do you mean that your PHP code is running on a MSWindows machine?

> my server is in UNIX

If the database server and the database client (PHP) are running on different machines then they cannot communicate via UNIX filesystem sockets.

> The code below is work fine, if my server is in TCP/IP.

No, either your interpretation or your description of events is incorrect. If you specify 'localhost' as the target host in a libmysql client (including PHP's mysql_ extension) then the client will try to connect via the (Unix) filesystem socket. OTOH. if you specify 127.0.0.1, it will use a TCP socket.

In the former scenario, the client gets the path to the socket from ~/.my.cnf, or in the absence of that file /etc/my.cnf, or if you've compiled the client lib yourself, $PREFIX/etc/my.cnf

Comment: sorry for my unclear question. I'm not sure what is the real problem that i have to ask too. What i have noticed is that, when open phpmyadmin (local machine), on the point server, it said: Server: Localhost via TCP/IP. But when i open phpmyadmin (hosting), on the point server, it said: Server: Localhost via UNIX socket. Then my code above cannot apply to Server: Localhost via UNIX socket.

Comment: I think the problem is that you're not supplying the correct to the socket. Your service provider should be able to provide this information.

Answer (score 3):

`hostname` + `:` + `/path/to/socket` is required

code snippet from https://www.php.net/function.mysql-connect

```
 $link = mysql_connect('localhost:/path/to/socket', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
```

**in your case**

```
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost:/path/to/socket');
```

**FYI, if you want to TCP socket**

```
$link = mysql_connect('hostname:port', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
```

Comment: when i try with it, it said: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/path/to/socket' (2)

Comment: @user2738520 replace /path/to/socket to your real path. if you don't know where is.... run `show variables like '%socket%'` in mysql console

Answer (score 0):

Just remove localhost.

```
define('DB_SERVER', '');
```

Or:

```
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error())
```

Comment: it gives you any kind of error? can you connect to the db using a console?

Answer (score 0):

In Unix you can also connect to server in same manner as

```
     $con = mysql_connect("host","username","password to connect toserver") or die("!server);
     $db  = mysql_select_db("yourdatabase",$con) or die("!db");
```