# Import MySQL data to Excel 365

Tags: mysql, excel, database, vba, unix

I'm trying to import data from a MySQL Database to an Excel 365 (32 bit) Workbook.

This is a DB I can link to without any issues :
[image: pic1]

This is the DB I can't link to :
[image: pic2]

I've downloaded the following connector :
`MySQL Connector Net 6.10.6`

I suspect that this is not the correct connector for the second DB.
The error is this :

```
[MySQL: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.]
```

Could someone point me to the beginning of a solution ?

I've also tried to connect via VBA but I also get an error which must be due to the same causes as above.

Comment: Is the second database located on your machine?

Comment: No, this is a distant server on an other machine.

Comment: Okay, do you have an IP or name for it?  The image you posted only shows `localhost` which refers to "your" computer.  If you *do* have one that's just not showing, maybe try `ping`ing it from the command prompt, ie: Start > Run > `cmd` [ᴇɴᴛᴇʀ] > `ping google.com` [ᴇɴᴛᴇʀ]

Answer (score 1):

If the database server and the database client (Excel) are running on different machines then they cannot communicate via UNIX filesystem sockets.

If you specify `localhost` as the target host in a libmysql client, then the client will try to connect via the (Unix) filesystem socket.

On the other hand, if you instead specify `127.0.0.1`, it will use a TCP socket.

---

### More Information:

- Stack Overflow : [How to connect to database when server is in Unix socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20117001/8112776) (MySQL/PHP)
- Wikipedia: [`Localhost`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)
- Wikipedia : [Unix domain socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket)
- Wikipedia : [TCP Socket definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket#Definition)
- MySQL.com : [Configuring a Connector/ODBC DSN on Windows with the ODBC Data Source Administrator GUI](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-configuration-dsn-windows-5-2.html)

---

## EDIT:

In response to your comment, the target host would be specified in the location specified on [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-configuration-dsn-windows-5-2.html), or it can also be installed via command line with [these](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-configuration-dsn-windows-5-2-command-line.html) steps.

**Also you might find this helpful:**

- mysql.com : [Using Connector/ODBC with Microsoft Word or Excel](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-wordexcel.html)
- mysql.com : [Using Connector/ODBC with Microsoft Access](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access.html)

---

### **Setting up a MySQL ODBC DSN on Windows 7 64-bit:**

I have a faint recollection of the last time I setup an ODBC DSN to MySQL.

It was a while ago so I might be mistaken on the details but I'm *pretty sure* that the only was I was able to get it working on a 64-bit system (possibly because the server was 32-bit?) was to install ***both*** the 32-bit and 64-bit drivers (from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.3.html)) into *separate folders*, rebooting between each install.  As I recall, it took a dozen install/uninstalls before I got it right.

Once it was properly installed, I had to administer it with Window's **32-bit version of ODBC Administrator**.

There's 2 versions of ODBC Administrator (aka 'Data Sources'), *confusingly*:

- My 64-bit version is located at : `c:\windows\system32\odbcad32.exe`
- My 32-bit version is located at : `c:\windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`

> <sub>Note that much of this is *from memory* and *unverified*!</sub>

---

I have this text file sitting in my "mySQL Notes" folder, so *I gather* I ended up using the command line to get it installed:

**`myodbc-installer -s -a -c1 -n "`** *`mysqlDSN`* **`" -t "DRIVER=MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver;SERVER=`** *`(server name)`* **`;DATABASE=`** *`(database name)`* **`;UID=`** *`(user name)`* **`;PWD=`** *`(password)`* **`"`**

In my case I was setting up connection to a web host server, so I referred to my CPanel for the `server` / `database` / `uid` values.

...and as I recall, I had to run it from the location of the 32-but version of the `myodbc-installer`.  Also, you'll have an `ODBC.INI` text file somewhere showing the configuration.

---

**More detail** under the plethora of information here:

- mysql.com : [MySQL Connector/ODBC Developer Guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/)

Comment: Thank you ashleedawg, your answer is very complete and i mch appreciated the links in the end.

I'm now trying to tamper with the ODBC Data Source Administrator in the DSN.

Would you be able to precise your answer as to where i would specify this target host ?

Comment: @UGC - You're welcome.  I will add some notes to my answer.  (I just had a flashback to the pain-in-the-@$$ that it was last time I had to set up an MySQL ODBC DSN since I'm running 64-bit Windows.)