# Why does connection string work on development machine only?

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, odbc

I have written 2 programs, one in VB6 and one in VBA for Excel. Calling the mySQL connection works perfectly in both on the development machine only. Trying to run either program on any other machine fails. Code is as follows:

```
Private Sub cmdErrors_Click()
On Error GoTo remote_err

Set myCon = New ADODB.Connection
strConnect = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI 
Driver};Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Port=3306;Database=cl22-budget;User=username; 
Password=password;Option=3;"

myCon.ConnectionString = strConnect
myCon.Open
MsgBox "Connected"
myCon.Close
Set myCon = Nothing
Exit Sub

remote_err:
Dim ErrorCollection As Variant
Dim ErrLoop As Error
Dim strError As String
Dim iCounter As Integer

On Error Resume Next

iCounter = 1
strError = ""
Set ErrorCollection = myCon.Errors
For Each ErrLoop In ErrorCollection
With ErrLoop
   strError = "error # " & iCounter & vbCrLf
   strError = strError & "ADO Error # " & .Number & vbCrLf
   strError = strError & " Description " & .Description & vbCrLf
   strError = strError & " Source " & .Source & vbCrLf
   MsgBox strError
   iCounter = iCounter + 1
End With
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error message actually?

Comment: Perhaps you don't have the MySQL ODBC driver setup on other machines? ...but you'll need to provide more information.

Comment: Nisfan, Thanks for the reply. the error number is ADO Error -2147467259. The error description is "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver found.

Comment: Ashleedawg. Thanks for the reply. Can I include the MYSQL ODBC driver as part of my app., and if so, how? What other information do you need?

Comment: Ashlee, sorry, another point. I have installed MYSQL ODBC driver on my test machine and the app. still gives the same error.

Comment: **More info on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49129975/8112776).**

Answer (score 0):

Install ODBC Driver and create a DSN for your DB and there it will ask for server address there you mention your server ip then it will work.

Comment: Does this mean that every distributed solution would need to include:

Comment: Sorry, wrong key. Does this mean that any distributed application would need to include a mySQL driver, and instructions on how to icreate a user DSN?