# Mysql ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql, unix-socket

I want to connect python with MySQL. On my local computer i get it like this:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                             user='test',
                             password='password',
                             database='database_name')
```

And this worked for me. But when i trying do it on VPS i got this one error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 920, in connect
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 724, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "save_payments.py", line 13, in <module>
    database='payment_reg')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 90, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 699, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 967, in connect
    raise exc
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
```

What`s wrong?
VPS admin told me about unix socket in mysql, but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to connect to database when server is in Unix socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117001/how-to-connect-to-database-when-server-is-in-unix-socket)

Answer (score 0):

When use wrong port,

```
curl -I localhost:33006
```

a im get error "curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 33006: **Connection refused**"

May be u need change port?

```
conn = pymysql.connect(
    host='localhost', 
    #charset='utf8mb4'
    port=3306, 
    user='root', 
    passwd='', 
    db='Work'
    )
```

Sometimes launching an application with an address may have different results

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='127.0.0.1', port='8050', debug=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', port='8050', debug=True)
```

There may be many more reasons, such as turning on the firewall. Have you seen the logs on the sql server? This way one can find any reason sql server didn't respond

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in mysql settings. It was listening only sockets connection. I added
`bind-address = 127.0.0.1`  in `my.cnf`, and commented all rows where was word socket))))